# Why the char arguments in scanf(%s) cannot be displayed in %c even disordered?

Tags: c, scanf, undefined-behavior, c-strings, stdio

```
char num1, num2;
scanf("%s %s", &num1, &num2);
printf("num1=%c, num2=%c", num1, num2);
```

I executed above code on Visual Studio in Mac with following cases:

```
Input: a b   => num1=, num2=b
Input: ab c  => num1=, num2=c
Input: a bc  => num1=c, num2=b
Input: ab cd => num1=d, num2=c
```

**I absolutely know the %s should be %c**, but I want to know why the first argument, char num1, cannot be displayed correctly in %s.

Moreover, the value of num2 precedes num1 if we input "a bc" or "ab cd". That looks confusing.

What's the reason or mechanism in C causes these strange output? Is the result the same on your computer? I think it is more important to know the reason rather than convention.

Comment: Because your code is absolutely wrong. %s reads a string and stores input + the terminating null character. How on earth is a char supposed to store two different things?

Comment: The variable `char num1` cannot be displayed with `printf` using the `%s` format because it requires a nul-terminated string, but you only have a single  `char`. You say *I know the `%s` should be `%c`* so why aren't you using it correctly? It's thoroughly unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Looks like strings are stored @ start addresses of chars and overwritten by each other ;-) Stack will be a bit messed up after...

Comment: In windows debug version Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'numX' was corrupted. A lot platform specific, but why RU trying to analyze code bug ??

Comment: I can accept the former 2 cases, but the latter 2 cases is confusing to me. I think the value of num1 should precede num2, but it didn't. I am curious about that situation.

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior.

The format specifier `%s` appends a zero character to the memory occupied by the corresponding argument.

Nevertheless I can explain the program output.

It seems that in the stack the variable `num1` follows the variable `num2`.

So when the input is

```
nput: a b
```

then to the address of the variable `num2` there is written two characters `'b'` and `'\0'`; The character `'\0'` occupies the memory of the variable `num1`.

So the output is

```
num1=, num2=b
```

When the input is

```
Input: ab c
```

when again the terminating zero is written in the memory occupied by the variable `num1`.

So you get the same output as above

```
num1=, num2=c
```

When the input is

```
Input: a bc
```

then in memory addressed by `&num2` there are written three characters: `'b'`, `'c'` and `'\0'`. So the character `'b'` is placed in the variable `num2`, the character `'c'` is placed in the variable `num1` and the terminating zero overwrites memory beyond the memory allocated for the variables.

So the output is

```
num1=c, num2=b
```

In the last case when the input is

```
nput: ab cd
```

then the output will be

```
num1=d, num2=c
```

as it is described above.